# Liferay-Spring MVC portlet importing multiple .js files

Tags: javascript, html, spring, liferay, portlet

I am porting my Spring MVC Servlet application to be compatible for deployment in Liferay. Am converting the application to a Spring MVC portlet. My application makes use of html + javascript as the frontend. Am unable to import .js or .css files in my index.html now because relative URL's are not working. Any help in this regard?

Comment: please show me the structure of your web project,and the location of your html pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your references are relative to your web application context references, which normally is the **portal ROOT context** including the portlet instance and some other dependent constructs (the related LR theme) in this case and **not the portlet (your application) context** which you assume. So, the solution is to use a portal instance specific global variable with the prefix in front of your path definitions. To achieve this you have to construct this path before you render your HTML page content. This is usually achieved using some Liferay utility classes e.g. in case of a JSP like this:

```
<link href="<%= PortalUtil.getStaticResourceURL(request, request.getContextPath() + "/css.jsp", portlet.getTimestamp()) %>"
```

Apparently, in case you do not have server side scripting like the JSP (BTW which I think is not a good idea) then you have to solve this using some other Java layer facility to write into your HTML before it is rendered by the browser.

Comment: This is exactly what my problem is. I have pure html frontend and thus can not use JSP tags etc.. Porting the FE to JSP implementation is too heavy at this moment and am trying for a solution for my situation. Pure HTMl + Spring  and I need to access the resources within the portlet. Any more help regarding injecting the value from  Java? Thankyou.

Comment: HTML is not a server side dynamic language! You use server side dynamic languages to generate the HTML which is then rendered by the browser on the client side. => You can't 'inject' into it! What you can do is use JavaScript code in your HTML to fetch these values from the server side during the rendering process. Look at this around the JavaScript section to see how to access services http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/accessing-liferay-services

Comment: By Inject, I meant to ask for a way by which I can get the values from Java to my js files. Maybe  like a service call to the BE. I do think that the link you provided would help me out.I shall explore in those lines and will update back. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide the location of the javascript and css files in your `liferay-portlet.xml` file, then it will be automatically added. You don't have to explicitly add the same into your html/jsp file.

in your liferay-portlet.xml, please add following attributes with the correct file path.

```
<header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
<header-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</header-portlet-javascript>
```

Also, if you want to access any static resources like image or anything else, you can use the path like this

```
<img src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/gear.png' class='settings' />
```

where the structure is like this

-portlet
---docroot
------images
--------gear.png